# Replace text that it is not part of some specific string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Taking the risk of not being explicit with the title, as I can't explain it better in a few words, I will describe exactly what I'm trying to achieve.

Lets say I have an article named "Ilha de Faro" and on its description I want to replace all occurrences of found related articles names (from db) by the corresponding link.

Nothing special so far. But if the related articles are "Faro", "Praia",  etc., and the article description contains the name, I don't want its words to be replaced, so that "Ilha de Faro" won't turn to "Ilha de Faro".

I am thinking of replacing all occurrences of the name by some special string (like #$%& or whatever) before the relations replacing takes place, and then replace back the special string to the article name. But what I want to know if there is a more direct and cleaner way to do it or is my little workaround a good way of doing it?

Thanks in advance for all answers

EDIT

I will give a more practical look to this. I haven't tried anything yet as I'm not at that stage, I'm just thinking ahead.
So, I have a table of articles, and an article can have n related articles.
Having the following article:

> Title: Ilha de Faro
>
> Description: Chamam-lhe Ilha de Faro mas na realidade é uma península, ligada à terra firme do lado leste, perto da elegante Quinta do Lago. Do lado oposto, par leste, fica a barra, por onde passa a navegação comercial e de recreio. Embora a zona fronteira a Faro esteja ocupada por alguma construção, o areal parece interminável e propicia belos instantes de repouso e fruição da natureza. De carro a partir da cidade são dez minutos de viagem, na direcção do aeroporto, havendo que contar com engarrafmentos e dificuldades de estacionamento no Verão. Carreiras de barco a partir do cais de Faro (donde também partem cruzeiros turísticos diários pelos canais, lagunas e ilhas da Ria Formosa) podem ser uma boa alternativa.
>
> Related Articles: Faro, Ria Formosa

What I want is to present the description of the article with links for the related articles that are present in the text, so it would something like this:

> Chamam-lhe **Ilha de Faro** mas na realidade é uma península, ligada à terra firme do lado leste, perto da elegante Quinta do Lago. Do lado oposto, par leste, fica a barra, por onde passa a navegação comercial e de recreio. Embora a zona fronteira a Faro esteja ocupada por alguma construção, o areal parece interminável e propicia belos instantes de repouso e fruição da natureza. De carro a partir da cidade são dez minutos de viagem, na direcção do aeroporto, havendo que contar com engarrafmentos e dificuldades de estacionamento no Verão. Carreiras de barco a partir do cais de `<a>`Faro`</a>` (donde também partem cruzeiros turísticos diários pelos canais, lagunas e ilhas da `<a>`Ria Formosa`</a>`) podem ser uma boa alternativa.

Notice the title in bold... it contains "Faro", which is the title of one of the related articles, but I don't wan't to have "Ilha de `<a>`Faro`</a>`".

What I initially thought was to create an array of related article titles for the pattern and another with the tagged titles for the replacement, but that would replace everything, even when the related article title is contained in the parent article title.

Comment: Why not just update it in the db?  It's hard to give even pseudo-code when you don't tell us what you've tried.

Comment: Give some sample input strings and expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I tried the solution that I proposed and it works. If anyone knows a more cleaner or "correct" way of doing this, suggestions are welcome.

Anyway, for anyone who has this question, here it is how I did it:

```
$descTemp = preg_replace('/'.$articleTitle.'/', '!-article_title-!', $description);
$descTemp2 = preg_replace($relatedArticleTitles, $relatedArticleLinks, $descTemp);
$finalDescription = preg_replace('/!-article_title-!/', $articleTitle, $descTemp2);
```